# mysql compare between fields

Tags: mysql, compare

I have a table with `timestamp` field and `expiry` field.
the `expiry` contain number of minutes (eg 15, 30, 60... )

I want to select only the rows that the diff between NOW() and the `timestamp`
field is larger the the value in `expiry`.

something like that:

```
select * FROM signals 
WHERE min(time_to_sec(timediff(now(), stime)))/60 > expiry
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and read about [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), you can reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) with `MINUTE` unit:

```
SELECT *
  FROM signals
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, stime, now()) > expiry
```